# How to open modal that is in child component from parent?

Tags: angular

I have layout form where I have button click. In other component I have layout that inside have modal, so when I click on layout click I want to open modal.

https://plnkr.co/edit/wJjPL9ZYYsOapw8ylD12?p=preview

This is my plunker. Any suggestion how can I do that ? I'm getting error that is child undefined.

```
  <layout>
     <div class="body">
      <common-modal  #childModal [title]="'common modal'"> 
    <div class="modal-body">
    {{5+7}} {{item}}
    Hi heloo </div>
    </common-modal> 
     </div>
    </layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the attribute on the template variable for `<layout>`:

```
<layout [child]="childModal">
...
```

and in layout component:

```
   @Input() child;
...
  show(){
   this.child.show();
  }
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/5XbuxoGG6NqomayLP4Ae?p=preview)

Comment: tnx...that was easy .. .for you :P